# How to get GIF animation to work when converting html to image/canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

In my application, I'm trying to convert a `div` to *image* and download it.

This is my usual `div`:

```
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;">
    <div style="width:100px;height:200px;float:left;">
        <img src="images/1.gif">
    </div>

    <div style="width:100px;height:200px;float:left;">
        <h1>Text comes here</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

My `div` usually contains a `gif` image & I'm using `HTML2CANVAS` for the *convertions*. This is my code for converting `HTML` to Image:

```
$('.toimage').click(function(){
  html2canvas($('#myDiv'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/gif');
      console.log(img);
      saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), 'file.gif');
      // also tested with the code below    
      // saveAs(img, 'file.gif');
    }
  });
});

function saveAs(uri, filename) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
    link.href = uri;
    link.download = filename;

    //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    //simulate click
    link.click();

    //remove the link when done
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  } else {
    window.open(uri);
  }
}
```

Everything works fine beside the `gif` animation. I already know in browsers like chrome, firefox & opera, browser ignores `canvas.toDataURL('image/gif')` and runs `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')`, so the code would be as: `data:image/png;base64` instead of `data:image/gif;base64`.

But I tested on more browsers and only browser that actually does `data:image/gif;base64` is **Safari**, but my problem is that even that the `div` has been converted to `data:image/gif;base64` my images *loses* the animation that `<img src="images/1.gif">` contains and only the first frame shows up.

Basically what I wish is to have/keep the animation to the image and only use whatever browser that supports that.

Any help and feedback are appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Please note that this question is not a duplicate to the question that was marked as duplicate for.

Comment: can you extend on why you think it is not? I added a link for the second step of your problem (the two steps being 1:"draw a gif animation", and 2:"export this animation". toDataURL and toBlob only exports the current content of your canvas, and a canvas always holds only a single image. So you won't have any animation from these methods. Only captureStream could.